# How to get references to list of cell (Excel) those not in range using formulars (For ex: Index, Indirect func)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, excel-2010

For example: I have a list of cell address something like this: `$A$1`, `$A$5`, `$B$5`.

How can I using functions like Indirect, Index to get references those cells?

Answer (score 0):

Use indirect,

```
=INDIRECT("$A$1")
```

if the data is in another sheet use;

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!$A$1")
```

Comment: No, what i mean is How to get references to cells those "not in range"